# Why should Ninject dlls be in the Web/bin folder? Can't I just put them in the GAC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dll, ninject, gac, ninject.web.mvc

My company has got a deployment policy (I skip the details) such that any 3rd party software should be installed in the GAC, whilst our libraries are in Web/bin folder. But this approach doesn't work with Ninject and MVC 3/4. Let's follow an example:

This is my dependencies binding code:

```
public class RequestorDependenciesRegistration : NinjectModule
{
  public override void Load()
  {
    Bind<IMyDearDependency>().To<MyDearImplementation>();
  }
}
```

And this is my MVC controller:

```
public MyController(IMyDearDependency something) {
  this.something = something; // 'something' is set only if Ninject dlls are in Web/bin... X-(
}
```

If Ninject dlls are in the GAC, it loads the module correctly, but when instantiating the MVC Controller the dependency is not injected (in some cases is null, in some cases MVC returns an error "No parameterless constructor etc etc"). If I manually copy Ninject*.dll in the Web/bin folder, than everything works fine, even without restarting IIS! Can't really understand why...

Even more surprisingly (for me), if I do something super-dirty like storing a reference to the Ninject Kernel instance in a public static property and use it as a ServiceLocator, it works! (Something dirty like this, in the MVC controller):

```
public MyController(IMyDearDependency something) { // 'something' is always null if Ninject is only in the GAC...
  var controller = Kernel.Get<MyController>()
  this.something = controller.something; // ... but this 'controller.something' is set, even if Ninject is only in the GAC!!! 8-O
}
```

Can anyone suggest me the reason why? And possibly a solution? :-) Many thanks!!

Comment: You can try to turn off the automatic extension loading and manually load the MvcModule: so when creating the Kernel use this settings : `var _kernel = new StandardKernel(
     new NinjectSettings() { LoadExtensions = false }, new MvcModule(), /* your other modules * /);`

Comment: :-O It is working now!!! I can't believe it!! Can you please explain me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ninject has a built in extension loading mechanism which is used to load the different extension like the `Ninject.Web.Mvc`.

But mechanism is looking only for the application folder to load the extensions so if your dll are in the GAC Ninject won't find them.

To solve this you can turn off the automatic extension loading and load the `MvcModule` module by hand when creating your `StandardKernel`:

```
var _kernel = new StandardKernel( 
    new NinjectSettings() { LoadExtensions = false }, 
    new MvcModule(),
    /* your other modules * /);
```

Comment: Many thanks! It also solved the problem that I had with Ninject.Extensions.Factory, I have been able to find a workaround reloading it explicitly, but now that everything is clear I see that it is cleaner to load it like this:

`var kernel = new StandardKernel(new NinjectSettings() { LoadExtensions = false }, new MvcModule(), new FuncModule());`
Thanks again! :-)